# Rails upgrade to angular 2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, angular

I would like to upgrade my existing Rails and Angular 1.x application. I'm following the ng-upgrade [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) and seeing that there are many dependencies including [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) and a few other javascript libraries. Ideally there would be a angular-2 gem that would have all the dependencies but I'm not able to find that. Next I looked for gem's for each dependency but there isn't one for tsd.

Does it make sense to switch over to a custom build strategy so I can use npm for javascript package management? I read [this](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/03/gulp-modern-approach-to-asset-pipeline-for-rails-developers/) article that recommends gulp but I do like the convenience of the asset pipeline.

Can anyone point me to examples of successfully using ng-upgrade with a rails project? Does it use a custom build solution like gulp or does it use the asset pipeline?

Comment: Why not manage angular and it's dependencies with gulp? https://viget.com/extend/gulp-rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 10):

My main suggestion is not upgrading yet to Angular2, is still heavily in development and you'll face a lot of this issues like not finding a gem for rails.

Anyway, currently, angular2 **can't be compiled with sprockets** (the default rails pipeline), so you really *want* a custom solution.

My main suggestion is go with webpack, other options are browserify or gulp (and others), that's mainly a matter of taste. Overall, configuring a pipeline for angular2 **is complicated**, you have to take care of `.d.ts` files through `typings` (which is the updated version of `tsd` which now is deprecated), you have to transpile your typescript through `tsc` and possibly through `babel` too if you want to use async/await (which are really cool). You'll lose the ability to reference to your files in rails like `image_path` and such, using a custom pipeline, so you want to take that into account too.

Typescript is much more complex to compile than simple coffeescript files, you depend on every other file it reference, since it needs to compile check against it, don't expect something straightforward.

That being said, if you really want to work with Rails and Angular (2 or not), the right way to handle it is to have **two separate projects**, one with only the Rails app and one with the AngularJS path. In this way you separate concern, you can have a custom pipeline for Angular2 without impacting Rails and you'll be forced to correctly code your Angular2 app by using Rails as a JSON API, as you should.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to keep it as simple as possible without using webpack or the asset pipeline. I put the `ts` files in `public` and configured rails to serve the npm assets through the pipeline.

I put up a starter project with this structure as an example: https://github.com/jonnysamps/rails-ng2-starter

In many ways it has the benefits of having separate backend/frontend projects but keeps all the code together.

Answer (score -1):

**use angularjs gem**

```
gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.8'
```

**insert into application.js**

```
  //= require angular
```

Comment: there is no `ngUpgrade` package in the angular-rails gem. There is an unstable option but that is only angular-2 https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts

Answer (score -1):

You can use http://bower.io/#install-bower and you can add two files to your the rails app `.bowerrc` and `bower.json` which is like `GemFile`

Comment: Angular2 doesn't support bower.

Comment: Your link, when you follow the instructions, installs AngularJS, not Angular2. It is possible to install Angular2 with bower using this command `bower install angular2-build` https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/vDQBKuf5HKY