# How to integrate a Rails application with Angular2 in a single application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, frontend, angular, rubymine

I know there are easy ways to get AngularJS working as the front end of a Ruby on Rails application such as the angularjs-rails gem, but I haven't been able to do the same thing with Angular 2. I know I could just make 2 different applications and just have them work together, but I'd rather have them in 1 app so I can just start the one app and it'll all run and do all the testing in one app at one time.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522294/rails-upgrade-to-angular-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686142/rails-vendor-folder-angular2-development-and-production

Answer (score -1):

As no "rails-angular2" gem has been released yet, you can do the integration by yourself following this link: http://programming.sereale.fr/20...
It is an example of integration without npm, but if you want to use npm you may still find a few interesting clues.

Comment: I think this is the correct link: https://programming.sereale.fr/2016/03/22/rails-and-angular2-react-the-tour-of-heroes/